# Nonseperable Hilbert space: Explicit ONB?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series, orthonormal

Every Hilbert space admits an ONB by axiom of choice.
For separable Hilbert spaces this can in fact be constructed by Gram-Schmidt.
For nonseparable Hilbert spaces there can be no general construction by induction.
However is there Hilbert spaces where one still knows some ONB explicitely?

Comment: Of course, take $\ell^2(I)$, where $I$ is uncountable. Then the elements $(\delta_i)_{i \in I}$ form an orthonormal basis where $(\delta_i)_j = 1$ for $i=j$ and $(\delta_i)_j = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: Is there any reason to use an abbreviation here? This isn't twitter - spell it out, at least once.

Comment: Things should be clear from the context...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can artificially construct such a thing, but whether there is any non-separable Hilbert space that is actually of some interest in which one can do such a thing is a more challenging question.

Here's an example: Look at the set of all functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ such that
$$
\sum_{x\in\mathbb R} |f(x)|^2 = \sup\left\{\sum_{x\in S} |f(x)|^2 : S\subseteq\mathbb R,\  S\text{ is finite} \right\}  < \infty.
$$
For every such function there are at most countably many $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)\ne0$.

Let the inner product be
$$
\langle f,g\rangle= \sum_{x\in\mathbb R} f(x)\overline{g(x)}
$$
where $\overline{c}=\text{complex conjugate of }c$.

Here is an orthonormal basis:
$$
\{ f_x : x\in\mathbb R\}, \text{ where }f_x(y) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }x=y, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thought already about sth in this direction - thx ;) ...oh these can be very important I guess

Comment: These kind of Hilbert spaces and uncountable basis are indeed useful in some version of Loop Quantum Gravity!